# github init error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm taking the ruby.railstutorial.org class (chapter 3) and I'm required to make a new github account. So I start up as normal.

```
$ git init
$ git commit -m "first commit"
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/sample_app.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Which is fine because it is only telling me that there is a github set up for this. Which is true, I can see that in my screenshot.

[image]

The next step accoding to github and my tutorial would be to:

```
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'git@github.com<username>/sample_app.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What could be causing this? I have not been promted for a password which I also find odd.

Comment: Is `'git@github.com<username>/sample_app.git'` the literal error? If you substituted your actual username, it looks like you forgot the colon.

Comment: Can you show the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: It seems that when you went to add the origin, there was something already called origin there. If you could answer @pktangyue's question, that would be very helpful. Alternatively, you could add it as a remote named `github` and then do `git push -u github master`

Comment: @Cairnarvon I initially thought the same but the colon is written in the original command.

Comment: @pktangyue @sigmavirus24. `git remote -v` shows 
`heroku git@heroku.com:<heroku-name>.git (fetch)`
`heroku git@heroku.com:<heroku-name>.git (push)`
`origin git@github.com<user_name>/sample_app.git (fetch)`
`origin git@github.com<user_name>/sample_app.git (push)`

again there doesn't seem to be a colon behind the github.com but in the command I have put the ':'.

Comment: It really seems, `github.comcantdutchthis` is missing a colon :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somehow ended up with an invalid URL for your `origin` remote; the colon is missing. You can update the URL like so:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/sample_app.git
```

Where `<username>` is your username.

Alternatively, you could manually edit the repository configuration file `.git/config` and change the `url` value under the `[remote "origin"]` section.

After that everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a github repo with that name you just clone it instead of creating a new one. In you console, trying doing:

```
git clone git@github.com:XXXXXX/sample_app.git
```

then continue with adding your first file, committing it, and pushing it.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. 
`$ git clone git@github.com:<user_name>/sample_app.git` shows the following output 

`fatal: destination path 'sample_app' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: Has your issue been solved? It looks like there is already a directory called 'sample_app' where you're trying to run the `git clone...` command. Try removing the 'sample_app' directory or go to a different directory before trying to run `git clone...` again.